# How to create line break in each paragraph in Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to create paragraph break in my app. Firebase is my back-end. But, Firebase doesn't support /n for separate paragraph. So, I found a solution from StackOverflow that is put `_b` instead of `_n` and after retrieving time replace this `_b` with `\n`. But, I don't know how to implement this method in my code.

This is my text portion

```
viewHolder.thrillersub_title.setText(model.getTitle());
```

This is my MainActivity

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_ottamooli_sub);

    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.OttamooliSubtoolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Ottamooli");

    if (getSupportActionBar()!=null){

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    }

    MobileAds.initialize(this,APP_ID);
    AdView adView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    adView.loadAd(adRequest);

    database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    MCC = database.getReference("Ottamooli2");

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_OttamooliSub);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager (layoutManager);

    if (getIntent() != null)
        categoryId = getIntent().getStringExtra("CategoryId");
        if (!categoryId.isEmpty() && categoryId != null) {
            loadListThrillerSubModel(categoryId);
        }
    }

    private void loadListThrillerSubModel(String categoryId) {

        adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<OttamoolisubModel, OttamooliSubViewHolder>(OttamoolisubModel.class,
            R.layout.ottamoolisub_items,
            OttamooliSubViewHolder.class,
            MCC.orderByChild("menuid").equalTo(categoryId)) {

            @Override
            protected void populateViewHolder(OttamooliSubViewHolder viewHolder, final OttamoolisubModel model, int position) {
                viewHolder.thrillersub_title.setText(model.getTitle());
                Picasso.get().load(model.getImage())
                .into(viewHolder.thrillersub_image);

               final OttamoolisubModel local = model;
               viewHolder.setItemClickListner(new ItemClickListner() {
                   @Override
                   public void onClick(View view, int position, boolean isLongClick) {          

                   }
               });

            }
        };

        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (item.getItemId()==android.R.id.home)
            finish();
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

This is my ViewHolder

```
public TextView thrillersub_title;
public ImageView thrillersub_image;

private ItemClickListner itemClickListner;

public void setItemClickListner(ItemClickListner itemClickListner) {
    this.itemClickListner = itemClickListner;
}

public OttamooliSubViewHolder(View itemView) {
    super(itemView);

    thrillersub_title = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.thrillerSub_name);
    thrillersub_image = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.thrillerSub_image);      
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    itemClickListner.onClick(v,getAdapterPosition(),false);
}
```

This is my modelcalss

```
private String title, image, menuid, cyid;

    public OttamoolisubModel() {
    }

    public OttamoolisubModel(String title, String image, String menuid, String cyid) {
        this.title = title;
        this.image = image;
        this.menuid = menuid;
        this.cyid = cyid;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(String image) {
        this.image = image;
    }

    public String getMenuid() {
        return menuid;
    }

    public void setMenuid(String menuid) {
        this.menuid = menuid;
    }

    public String getCyid() {
        return cyid;
    }

    public void setCyid(String cyid) {
        this.cyid = cyid;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

on

```
setTitle(String title)
    this.title = title.replace("_b","\n");
```

That being said, if you have any occurrences of _b in your title outside of that, this could be problematic, and you'll need to parse it better.

Comment: Thanku. i will try this

Comment: In the model class.